# Ejecutar varias rutas .exe con c++

Tags: c++, ejecutar

estoy realizando una aplicación que necesito que tras realizar unas comprobaciones, ejecute una ruta que monta en función de lo que encuentre.

El problema, es que es una ruta compuesta, podriamos decir que tiene tres partes:

ruta : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\miAplicacion\Sql32.accde"  /WRKGRP  "C:\miAplicacion\app2021.mdw"

Como veis, el programa que arranca la aplicación en c++ es creado en Access. El inconveniente que me encuentro es que no sé de qué forma, puedo ejecutar toda la ruta completa. Para que abra la aplicación.

Este codigo, deberia de ejecutar al ruta, ya que así lo hace si en lugar de la ruta compuesta, le paso la ruta de ejecucción del access.

```
string ruta = "\"" + archivoAccess + "\"" + " " + "\"" + rutaCompleta + "\\" + archivoBaseDatos + "\"" + " " + WRKGRP + " " + "\"" + rutaCompleta + "\\" + archivoPrograma + "\"" ;

const char *rutaCompleta = ruta.c_str();

STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // start the program up
    CreateProcess(rutaCompleta ,   // the path
        NULL,//argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
    );
    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

Entiendo que es problema de interpretación tema de como compone el string ya que al tener las comillas y varias rutas de ejecución...

Pero no doy con la solución.

Si me podéis ayudar, os lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    system("C://Program Files//Microsoft Office//root//Office16//MSACCESS.EXE");
    system("C://miAplicacion//Sql32.accde//WRKGRP");
    system("C://miAplicacion//app2021.mdw");
    
    return 0;
}
```

> Puedes probar con esto, el problema es que el primer system no se ejecuta por el espacio que separa a "program" de "files". No sé como arreglarlo, pero deberian abrirse los otros dos a ti ya que son tus carpetas. aunque el 2º necesita una extensión de archivo.

Comment: No respondas si no sabes o si no estás seguro.